# Find Bifurcations Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

> Hello everbody !
>
> How to find bifurcations points without bifurcation diagramm? (for 2D
> system)
> For example, if I want to  solve this problem, how can I proceed?
>
> ${dz\over dt}= y- {1\over 3}z^3+(r-1)z$
>
> ${dy\over dt}=-z$
>
> I found fixed point $(0,0)$ and Jacobian matrix
> $\begin{bmatrix}r-1 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$
> Characteristic polynomial: $(r-1)^2-4$
> when $r=3$ => two equilibrium points: $A= (r-1)/2$
>
> when $r>3$ => two fixed points : $B= {(r-1)-\sqrt{(r-1)-4}\over 2}$ or $B= {(r-1)+\sqrt{(r-1)-4}\over 2}$
> Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, 
and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them 
give their answers at the right level. As it is, since your question is phrased as an isolated problem without
any further information or context, it does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may 
attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, consider editting the question to add more content.

Comment: @peter Ok I will do that! Thank you !

Comment: @Beatrice "Infinite monkey" was the one to point that out :) I only know the bifurcation phenomenon from the logistic map, unfortunately, I do not know how the bifurcation occurs here.

Comment: @peter Ahh right! I didn't notice ! It's okay ! Thank you anyway :p

Comment: @infinitemonkey ok i will put more informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bifurcation point typically describes a point in parameter space (in this case, the values that $r$ can take) at which the stability, nature or existence of equilibrium points changes. Therefore you should consider the linear stability of the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ as you vary $r$. The value(s) of $r$ at which the stability or nature of the point changes will be the bifurcation point that you're looking for.

Note: by the 'nature' of an equilibrium point I'm referring to whether it is e.g. a saddle or a node, which depends on the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at the equilibrium point. A quick search will give you detailed information on the classification of equilibrium points in plane autonomous systems.

Edit: more complete solution:

The eigenvalues of the Jacobian are the roots of 
$$\lambda^2-\lambda(r-1)+1=0\,,$$
which are given by
$$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{(r-1) \pm \sqrt{(r-1)^2-4}}{2}\,.$$
The stability of the equilibrium point is determined by the sign of the real part of $\lambda_{\pm}$. When the square root is real (i.e. when $r\geq3$ or $r\leq-1$), we have that $\lambda_{\pm}<0$ for $r<1$, so the equilibrium point is a stable node, with the conditions satisfied when $r\leq-1$. When $r\geq3$ we have the $\lambda_{\pm}>0$, so we have an unstable node.

For $-1<r<3$ the square root is imaginary, so we now see spirals/centres. We get a centre precisely when $\Re(\lambda_{\pm})=0$, i.e. when $r=1$. This is an example of a linearly neutrally stable point, where linear stability analysis is unlikely to be a good indicator of phase plane behaviour. For $r<1$ we have a negative real part, so we have a stable spiral. For $r>1$ we have a positive real part, so we have an unstable spiral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found 3 for bifurcation point. But how to define the nature of the equilibium points??

Comment: There is only one equilibrium point, $(0,0)$, and what we need to do is find the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at $(0,0)$. The linear stability of the equilibrium point then depends on the sign of the real part of the eigenvalues, and the nature can also be found from them (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_plane).

Comment: I don't understand ...I have one equilibrium point $(0,0)$ . The eigenvalues of the Jacobian at $(0,0)$ is the solution of  the characteristic polynomial ($(r-1)^2-4$). But when r=3 there is one eigenvalue: $ (r-1)/2$, and $(3-1)/2=1$ so it's an unstable node . When r>3 => two eigenvalues =>  $ {(r-1)-\sqrt{(r-1)-4}\over 2}$ or $={(r-1)+\sqrt{(r-1)-4}\over 2}$; If r=4 => the two eigenvalues >0 so it's an unstable node???? I'm not sure...

Comment: The polynomial that you're quoting isn't a polynomial, it's a function of the parameter $r$. Introduce a variable, say $\lambda$, to represent eigenvalues of $J(0,0)$, then solve the resulting polynomial for $\lambda$. It is then helpful to always think of there as being two eigenvalues, and the signs of the real parts of the eigenvalues determines the stability as you've said. I will post a worked solution later if you're still having troubles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. I have few questions. 1) Why the solution of the polynomial is $ {(r-1)-\sqrt{(r-1)^2-4}\over 2}$ or $ {(r-1)+\sqrt{(r-1)^2-4}\over 2}$?  For me, the solution of the polynomial is $ {(r-1)-\sqrt{(r-1)^2-4}\over 2}$ or $ {(r-1)+\sqrt{(r-1)^2-4}\over 2}$ only if  the discriminant of the  polynomial  is > 0. Why the real part of $λ$ is the square root? How did you find when the square root is real? Did you use a formula?

Comment: @Beatrice The roots of the polynomial are given by the quadratic formula, and always hold regardless of whether or not the square root is real, as when dealing with eigenvalues we do not presume that they are real (in general they are complex). So the solution is as I've given even if the discriminant is negative. The square root is real when its argument is non-negative, i.e. when $(r-1)^2-4 \geq 0$, which gives the conditions that I mentioned. The real part of $\lambda$ is not necessarily the square root, particularly as the square root is often purely imaginary, so could not contribute.

Comment: So, the solution of a characteristic polynomial (for example, $ax^2+bx+c$ )is always $$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{discriminant}}{2a}\,.$$? How to find the real part of $λ$? Here, you found two bifurcations points: -1 and 3 randomly ( you consider the linear stability of the equilibrium point as you vary r) ? But can we use a formula ?

Comment: That is the solution of the general quadratic that you quoted, but the characteristic polynomial of a general matrix will not always be a quadratic (e.g. a 3x3 matrix gives a cubic in general). The real part of $lambda$ is easy if the square root is imaginary: it is simply the '-b/(2a)' term in your general solution quoted above. If the square root is real then it affects the real part of $\lambda$, requiring more care. The -1 and 3 are not random, they are the values when the discriminant changes sign. Also $r=1$ is a bifurcation point (between stable and unstable spirals).

Comment: Oh thank you !!!I am starting to understand ! If we have a 2x2 matrix, the solution of the characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{(-b) \pm \sqrt{discriminant}}{2a}\,.$$ ? In this case, the root is not imaginary so we have to consider the root and (r-1) ?

Comment: Yes that's right, where the $a,b,c$ come from the entries of the matrix (characteristic polynomial is det$(A-\lambda I)$). The square root is imaginary for certain values of $r$, and for those values the real part of $\lambda$ is just $-b/(2a)$. When the root is real we have to look at whether it is larger in magnitude than $b$ to see whether it can change the sign of the eigenvalue (as that is the only thing determining stability). In our case, as we are subtracting $4$ from $b^2$ before taking the square root, it is not large enough to change the sign of the eigenvalue, so we can ignore it.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much =)) !!!

Comment: Not a problem! Hope it helped! If it did then accepting my answer would be great if you don't mind!

Comment: Of course !!!! I will do that